# DistinctUntilChanged only compares equal values

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rxbluetooth

```
let manager = CentralManager(queue: .main)
manager.observeStateWithInitialValue()
    .filter {$0 == .poweredOn}
    .flatMap { _ in manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID.myDevice.mainService])}
    .filter { $0.peripheral.identifier == someSavedIdentifier}
    .flatMap { $0.peripheral.establishConnection() }
    .flatMap { $0.discoverServices([CBUUID.myDevice.mainService]) }
    .flatMap { Observable.from($0) }
    .flatMap { $0.discoverCharacteristics([CBUUID.myDevice.businessSecret]) }
    .flatMap { Observable.from($0) }
    .flatMap { $0.observeValueUpdateAndSetNotification() }
    .distinctUntilChanged({ (old, new) -> Bool in
        if let oldValue = old.value?.toInt(),
           let newValue = new.value?.toInt() {
            print("old: \(oldValue), new: \(newValue)")
        }
        return old.value?.toInt() == new.value?.toInt()
    })
    .takeUntil(viewDidDisappear)
    .subscribe(onNext: { businessSecretValue in
        // business logic...
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

the distinctUntilChanged works on an Observable (which is a Bluetooth characteristic). I’m trying to have the sequence only contain the characteristics that have a distinct value. But it seems to somehow skip the comparison when they are not equal.

Output sample:

```
old: 24, new: 24
old: 24, new: 24
old: 24, new: 24
old: 24, new: 24
old: 29, new: 29
old: 29, new: 29
old: 29, new: 29
```

This is causing it to never find distinct elements. Why isn’t there a line that says:

```
old: 24, new: 29
```

Comment: Can you show the minimal code the reproduces this?

Comment: @NewDev I updated the code, hope this helps.

Comment: Just a guess, but if it's possible that one of the value after `24` is a `nil`, then the `print` would be skipped because one of the `if let`s would not be satisfied

Comment: Not understanding where the problem is. You print within the `distinctUntilChanged` block, which is called every time a new value arrives, hence the prints. If you want to check that `distinctUntilChanged` properly works, you should put the print downstream

Comment: @Cristik the problem is that it’s never finding distinct elements except for the first element of course; in other terms it only enters the subscribe for the first element received then it stops; to discover why i placed the printing inside the distinctUntilChanged to check what it is comparing, none of the ouputs contained 24 as old and 29 as new. Why is that?

Comment: As @NewDev suggested, it might be the sequence is `nil`, 24, 24, 24, 24, `nil`, 29, 29, 29, thus the `if-let` won't be entered for a 24-29 combination. Try printing without the `if-let`, to see what actually happens, this should give you a better insight of the values that flow through the pipeline.

Comment: @Cristik I tried that before posting the question, but just a reminder, the main problem is that it’s not getting to the subscribe, the printing was just to debug, so if the nil was the problem it would have gotten into the subscribe even if the printing did not reflect the different old and new values :(

Comment: @Eddy can you post a snapshot of the data without the `if-let`? Curios what values flow through your pipeline.

Comment: For starters, I see you're using RxBluetoothKit so I suggest using their convenience helper methods, it'll make the chain above much shorter. Additionally, is there only one peripheral you're connecting to?

Comment: @Adis yes 1 peripheral

Comment: What happens when you add a .debug just before the distinctUntilChanged?

Comment: @Adis keeps printing (init(userRepository:badgeFilterUseCase:rewardsRepository:latestRewardsFilterUseCase:badgesRepository:)) -> Event next(RxBluetoothKit.Characteristic)

Answer (score -1):

I see that

I see that `observeValueUpdateAndSetNotification()` returns an `Observable<Characteristic>` and that `Characteristic` is a class. My guess is that `value?.toInt()` is getting changed by something under the hood.

I also see that it is Equatable. Which leads me to wonder why you are even breaking it down in the first place. You should be able to simply do `.distinctUntilChanged()` instead of providing a closure.

**Old answer**

I think you aren't looking closely enough. Note that this:

```
Observable.from([24, 24, 29, 29])
    .debug("in")
    .distinctUntilChanged({ (old, new) -> Bool in
        print("old:", old, " - new:", new)
        return old == new
    })
    .debug("out")
    .subscribe()
```

Produces this output:

```
2020-10-20 20:35:00.056: out -> subscribed
2020-10-20 20:35:00.057: in -> subscribed
2020-10-20 20:35:00.058: in -> Event next(24)
2020-10-20 20:35:00.058: out -> Event next(24)
2020-10-20 20:35:00.058: in -> Event next(24)
old: 24  - new: 24
2020-10-20 20:35:00.058: in -> Event next(29)
old: 24  - new: 29                                  <-- There it is
2020-10-20 20:35:00.058: out -> Event next(29)
2020-10-20 20:35:00.058: in -> Event next(29)
old: 29  - new: 29
2020-10-20 20:35:00.058: in -> Event completed
2020-10-20 20:35:00.058: out -> Event completed
2020-10-20 20:35:00.058: out -> isDisposed
2020-10-20 20:35:00.058: in -> isDisposed
```

Comment: I tried your code, works like a charm. But my code doesn’t work, there’s no way I’m not looking closely because the output i placed above in my question is a copy-paste version, plus it’s never going into the subscribe which proves that it’s never finding distinct elements :(

Comment: the characteristic is equatable not its value i guess